# LZMA for Delphi

Tags: algorithm, delphi

I got a LZMA library on 7-zip site, but that didn't worked.
I'm not using files, just stream.
And for some why the library on 7-zip site just write the header on the stream but not compress the stream.

Some one faced the some problem ? Have some example ? Know other LZMA library for Delphi ?

Tks

Comment: What did you try? Sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A patch for Delphi Zip that support both LZMA and Zip64 is ready: [delphi-zip](https://github.com/ccy/delphi-zip)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any LZMA experience myself but the [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) project by Jordon Russell makes use of LZMA as one of the compression options when making the installer executables.

You can download the full source from his website and use it as a reference.

HTH,
Ryan

Comment: Tks by the hint.
I got the source, and examined it what i realized is that in it's code he calls some dlls to do the hard work, so, no success yet. 
:/

Comment: If you have access to the LZMA .obj files you should be able to use the much of the same code and have the Delphi compiler include the obj files into your exe.  This is how the ZLIB stuff in Delphi generally works.